# Create shortcut of directory

Tags: powershell

I want to create shortcut of Autostart directory on my desktop.

I know how to create shortcut of any application for example notepad but how can I create shortcut of directory?

I am trying something like this

```
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$objShortCut = $objShell.CreateShortcut($env:USERPROFILE + "\Desktop" + "\Autostart.lnk")
$objShortCut.TargetPath="C:\Users\" + $env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
$objShortCut.Save()
```

Errors:

```
+ $objShortCut.TargetPath="C:\Users\" + $env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Ro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `"C:\Users\" +`.

```
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$objShortCut = $objShell.CreateShortcut($env:USERPROFILE + "\Desktop" + "\Autostart.lnk")
$objShortCut.TargetPath=$env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
$objShortCut.Save()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Environment Class:

```
$StartupFolder = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Startup')
$DesktopFolder = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$link = $wshshell.CreateShortcut((Join-path $DesktopFolder "Autostart.lnk"))
$link.TargetPath = $StartupFolder
$link.Save()
```